# Visually labelling coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, coordinates

Sometime it is very useful to be able to see where the `\coordinates` that you are defining really are in a diagram. I am using what I think it's an hack to do it, defining a command and then change the definition in the final run (see below).

The first problem is that I would like that the pin did not change anything in the graph (in this case, they are changing at least the bounding box). Is it possible to have a kind of "overlay" pin? I checked that adding `overlay` to the pin options did not work...

And the second one... is there a better way to do it? For example, with a `style` that could be applied to `every coordinate`?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    % \def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
    \def\coord(#1){node[pin={[red]45:#1}](#1){}}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, 
        ]
        \draw (0, 0) to [sV=$v_s$] ++(0,-5) node[ground](GND){};
        \draw (0, 0) to[short,-*] ++(2,0) \coord(inb) to[R, l=$R_1$] (inb |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (inb) to [short] ++(2,0) \coord(re) to [R=$r_e$, i=$i_e$, -o] ++(0, -2.5) \coord(q1e) node[below right]{E};
        \draw (q1e) to[R, l=$R_{E1}$] (q1e |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (q1e) to[short] ++(2,0) \coord(q1e2) to[R, l=$R_{E2}$] (q1e2 |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (re) to [short] (q1e2 |- inb) to[short]  ++(2,0) \coord(alpha) to[american controlled current source,  l=$\alpha i_e$, -o] ++(0, -2.5) \coord(q1c);
        \draw (q1c) to[R=$R_C$] (q1c |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (q1c) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) node[right]{$v_o$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the `overlay` option, it is only added to the node but not to the edge of the pin.  To this end you have to add the `pin edge=overlay` option on top.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    % \def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
    \def\coord(#1){node[pin={[pin edge=overlay,overlay,red]45:#1}](#1){}}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, 
        ]
        \draw (0, 0) to [sV=$v_s$] ++(0,-5) node[ground](GND){};
        \draw (0, 0) to[short,-*] ++(2,0) \coord(inb) to[R, l=$R_1$] (inb |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (inb) to [short] ++(2,0) \coord(re) to [R=$r_e$, i=$i_e$, -o] ++(0, -2.5) \coord(q1e) node[below right]{E};
        \draw (q1e) to[R, l=$R_{E1}$] (q1e |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (q1e) to[short] ++(2,0) \coord(q1e2) to[R, l=$R_{E2}$] (q1e2 |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (re) to [short] (q1e2 |- inb) to[short]  ++(2,0) \coord(alpha) to[american controlled current source,  l=$\alpha i_e$, -o] ++(0, -2.5) \coord(q1c);
        \draw (q1c) to[R=$R_C$] (q1c |- GND) node[ground]{};
        \draw (q1c) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) node[right]{$v_o$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]